# Very confused about ScrollMagic's onLeave event

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax, scrollmagic

I've done a very bare ScrollMagic site based on one of the tutorials: http://www.oneniceday.com/Parallax-1/P2.html

If you View Source, then at the very end, there's this line:

```
triggerElement: "#pinned-trigger1",
duration: 2000,
triggerHook:"onLeave"
```

I don't understand about the "triggerHook:onLeave" line.

When is this onLeave event triggered?

I've been spending the past 2 days camping at the ScrollMagic documentation and reference site trying to figure out how the triggerElement and Hook works and when are the events like onLeave, onEnter, onCenter called but well....

Tks!

```js
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

//create a new Scene
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "#pinned-trigger1",
  duration: 2000, //pin the #pinned-trigger1 element for 2000px
  //of scrolling
  triggerHook: "onLeave", //trigger the setpin method only when
  //top of #pinned-trigger section has hit the top of browser
  //window
  reverse: true
}).setPin("#pinned-element1").addTo(controller);
```

```css
<style type="text/css"> html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
section {
  text-align: center;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}
.full-screen {
  height: 100%;
  /* makes panels the entire window height */
}
.blue {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #3883d8;
}
.red {
  background-color: #cf3535;
}
.orange {
  background-color: #ea6300;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

</head>

<body>
  <main class="full-screen" role="main">
    <section class="full-screen blue">
      <div>
        <h1>Basic Pin</h1>
        <p>Elements are pinned for their respective pixel value set as the duration and released again.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="pinned-trigger1" class="full-screen orange">
      <div id="pinned-element1">
        <p>This element will be pinned once it's trigger hits the top of the viewport and will have a duration of window height minus 100</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="pinned-trigger2" class="full-screen red">
      <div id="pinned-element2">
        <p>This element will be pinned for a duration of 150px</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="full-screen blue">
      <div>
        <p>Section Four!</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**trigger Hook-**
there are 3 types of trigger Hooks which defines the start point of your animation, the position of the trigger Hook is in relation to the viewport.

`onEnter` => 1 (top of the screen)

`onCenter` => 0.5 (center of the screen)

`onLeave` => 0 (bottom of the screen)
By default trigger Hook is "onCenter"

**trigger Element -**

This defines the div ID or class the animation should start from. Once this trigger Element hits the trigger Hook your animation begins.